# Displaying images with different sizes on a single window using CUDA OpenGL

Tags: opengl, cuda

I have two images with different sizes (size of image 1: W1*H1, size of image 2: W2*H2). These images were correctly processed by launching two Cuda kernels. Now I'd like to display them in a single widow using CUDA-OpenGL interop. It is ok whether are shown horizontally or vertically. The application works fine for one image on a window. I would appreciate it if someone could advise me how I could properly display multiple images on a single window?

```
unsigned int ScreenWidth = W1+W2;
unsigned int ScreenHeight = H1+H2;    
static void display (void)
 {
   unsigned char *ImPtr;
   size_t mapped_size;
   checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &pbo_r, 0));
   checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer((void **)&ImPtr, &mapped_size,pbo_r));

   CrossSectionKernel<<<grid1, block1>>>(ImPtr, W1, H1);

   EnFaceKernel<<<grid2, block2>>> &ImPtr[W1*H1], W2, H2);

   checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &pbo_r, 0));

   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
   glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, bufferObj);
   glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight,GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
   glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0);

   glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
   glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
   glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
   glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

   glBegin(GL_QUADS);
     glVertex2f(0, 0);
     glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
     glVertex2f(0, 1);
     glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
     glVertex2f(1, 1);
     glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
     glVertex2f(1, 0);
     glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
   glEnd();
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
  glutSwapBuffers();
  glutPostRedisplay();
 }

void initGL(int *argc, char **argv)
{
  glutInit(argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
  glutInitWindowSize(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight);
  glutCreateWindow("One Frame");

  glewInit();
} 

void createPBO()
{
  glGenBuffers(1, &bufferObj);
  glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, bufferObj);
  glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, (W1*H1 + W2*H2)*sizeof(unsigned char), NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
  glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0 );
  checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer(&pbo_r, bufferObj, cudaGraphicsMapFlagsWriteDiscard));
}

void createTexture()
{
 glGenTextures(1,&textureID);
 glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
 glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
 glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

 glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
 glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  initGL(&argc, argv);

  cudaDeviceProp prop;
  int dev;

  memset(&prop, 0, sizeof(cudaDeviceProp));
  prop.major = 1;
  prop.minor = 0;
  checkCudaErrors(cudaChooseDevice(&dev, &prop));

  cudaGLSetGLDevice(dev);

  glutDisplayFunc(display);

  createPBO();
  createTexture();
  glutMainLoop();  

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: CrossSection? EnFace? Do you happen to work with OCT images?

Comment: Yes! I plan to show cross section and en-face images in one window. Many thanks for your hint. I created two PBOs and textures separately, and also copied the cross section and en-face image data by using separated targets (two different pointers pointing to separated PBOs). Now my question is: how I could display these two PBOs in one single window?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm legally bound not to tell you anything more. I'm co-founder of Optores http://optores.com and we specialize in ultra-high speed OCT. Also today our paper on realtime MHz-OCT got published: http://dx.doi.org/10.1364/BOE.5.002963 so your question touches a subject on which I must not release information, that might be trade secrets of our company.

Comment: I know that displaying images is not really relevant to that part, but you're doing OCT work, so that's why I have to cover my buttocks here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand. Is it possible for you to introduce me some useful books/resources that I can gain more information about display part of CUDA-OpenGL interop part?

Comment: On that part I've never consulted anything other than the official CUDA documentation (that ship with the CUDA SDK). I guess having a lot of experience and intimate knowledge about OpenGL helps a lot finding your way around with CUDA/OpenGL interop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you a hint: You're doing two different operations, but you're using only one target location `ImPtr`. Either copy the contents of the memory `ImPtr` points to, to OpenGL textures immediately after each CUDA kernel execution, or use two different PBOs. You should use two textures regardless.